# NoClassDefFound in Java / Eclipse: How do I make a clean and easy reference to another project?

Tags: java, eclipse, reference, project

I have been searching for this problem all over, and a lot of ppl has the same problem. However, I cannot find any good explaination or how to actually solve this issue.

The problem is that then I add a Project Refernce in my project, it will not give me any compile-time errors. However, when I use the referenced project in my main project, I get the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

To me, this is very very insane. If I add a Project Reference, I expect that project to be available during runtime. It is not, apparently.

I add it by RIGHT-CLICK on the Project --> Properties --> Projects --> and then add my project that is in the workspace.

And no, I dont really want to export my referenced project to a JAR and import that file, since that mean I have to import it every time I change the referenced project.

It should be so easy - like in Visual Studio - to add the project and then be done with it.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'add a project reference' and 'use the referenced project in my main'?  Is your noClass error when you run the application inside Eclipse, or outside of it?

Comment: I have my MainProject. And then I have my MiscLibrary. I add the MiscLibrary project to my MainProject, as described above. I then run the MainProject (debug) in Eclipse. And then I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I found the problem.

The "MiscLibrary", the project I am referencing from my MainProject, has another external JAR referenced. If that wasnt also imported in the MainProject, I get those weird errors.

Its very bad that 
1) I can compile it without any errors or warning!
2) In runtime, the error messages give no indication what so ever that I am missing a reference to another library. Instead, it says it cannot find MiscLibrary, when in fact the problem is the missing external lib in MiscLibrary...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding the project reference or perhaps as well as adding the project reference, you should also link the sources.

- Right click on your current project
- Select java build path
- On the first tab, click the link sources button and navigate to the root dir of the `src` files of your other project,
- Select the source directory, the one before your package directories
- Save it, Clean and build.

*EDIT*

Failing that,

There is a Project tab  next to the Source tab, try adding the project there.

Comment: I cant get that to work in an easy way. If I do that, then it looks like the files are "imported" to my MainProject. But I cannot compile, since the package is wrong (it asks me if I want to move it to my MainProject package, which I of course dont want to). Also, any external JARs in the project that I just added isnt there, so I get compile errors there too...

Comment: I know about the "Projects"-tab. I mentioned that in my original post above, and how that doesn't work in runtime, thus the problem =(

Comment: I assumed you meant the "Project References" option on the left menu.
This is different from the "Projects" tab on the "Build path" page.